# Trouble with countability axioms

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space having the property that every $ x \in X$ has some open neighborhood which is homeomorphic to some open subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ . Give some justification or a counterexample for each of the following questions.
(i) Is $X$ a first countable space? 
(ii) Is $X$ a second countable space?

So far, I know that $X$ is first countable, but not second countable.

For (ii) I know that we can construct a counterexample by taking a large collection of disjoint copies of $\Bbb{R}^2$, so large that the space does not remain second countable. But I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Do you think both are true? False? Just one of them? What does your gut tell you? What have you tried and where did you get stuck? The more you tell us, the easier it is to actually help you.

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  If you are wanting Math.SE to be your research assistant and look up the definitions for you, please indicate that's your expectation.

Answer (score 4):

Your hunch for the second is perfectly correct. You simply define $X = \coprod_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}^2$; that is, you take $\mathbb{R}$ copies of $\mathbb{R}^2$. This is not second countable, since it cannot have a countable basis.

One should note that there is also a connected version of this, the so-called "long line" which also is not second countable.

For the first, remember that first countable means that each point has a countable system of neighbourhoods. If each point is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, which itself is first countable...

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to take an uncountable disjoint union of copies of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (as noted in the current version of the question)?  My tired old eyes make this appear to be a product of copies of $\mathbb{R}^2$, though checking the $\LaTeX$ showed you have a coproduct in mind.

Comment: Yeah, I use $\coprod$ to mean disjoint union.